# ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 when using the lead function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have been working on a query and couldn't figure out the solution for this error. Hope can get insights from the community on how to solve this:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(RTC_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') || ',' || lpad(rtc_event_order_seq, 3, '0'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3') AS TIME_STAMP,
TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char((Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP,1)over(order by RTC_TIMESTAMP)), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') || ',' || lpad(rtc_event_order_seq, 3, '0'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3') AS NEXT_TIMESTAMP
from mytable
```

the Error I have been getting is:

```
ora-01841 full year must be between 4713 and 9999 and not be 0
```

Comment: As Oracle told you - during evaluation of these functions, the "year" value wasn't in that range (btw. it is between **-**4713, otherwise you wouldn't be able to display current year (among many others)). Sample data might help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the final row in the result set, when there is no `lead` row to get values from. `Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP,1)over(order by RTC_TIMESTAMP)` returns null, you concatenate a comma and milliseconds value. The `next_timestamp` calculation ends up as:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(',001', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3')
```

which is what throws that error. You can see that if you run the query without the `to_timestamp()` calls.

The value is probably wrong anyway - presumably you should be looking at the lead `rtc_event_order_seq` as well - which would also be null, and trying to convert just `','` would also fail.

You can wrap the `next_timestamp` is a case expression to avoid the issue:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(RTC_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') || ',' || lpad(rtc_event_order_seq, 3, '0'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3') AS TIME_STAMP,
  case when Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP,1)over(order by RTC_TIMESTAMP) is not null then
    TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char((Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP,1)over(order by RTC_TIMESTAMP)), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
      || ',' || lpad(Lead(rtc_event_order_seq,1)over(order by RTC_TIMESTAMP), 3, '0'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3')
    end AS NEXT_TIMESTAMP
from mytable
```

| TIME_STAMP | NEXT_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.002000000 | 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.001000000 |
| 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.001000000 | *null* |

But rather than converting to and from strings, you can add multiples of one millisecond directly:

```
select RTC_TIMESTAMP + (rtc_event_order_seq * interval '0.001' second) AS TIME_STAMP,
  case when Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP, 1) over (order by RTC_TIMESTAMP) is not null then
    Lead(RTC_TIMESTAMP, 1) over (order by RTC_TIMESTAMP)
      + (Lead(rtc_event_order_seq, 1) over (order by RTC_TIMESTAMP) * interval '0.001' second)
    end AS NEXT_TIMESTAMP
from mytable
```

| TIME_STAMP | NEXT_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.002000000 | 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.001000000 |
| 01-JAN-22 12.13.14.001000000 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SQjMYGJ_)